# Auto generate annotations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

How can i do this?
I try to run:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities BlogWebBundle
```

But i get class without annotations ("@orm ..." in comments)
Like in this example http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine/orm/overview.html

```
// Sensio/HelloBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace Sensio\HelloBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @orm:Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @orm:Id
     * @orm:Column(type="integer")
     * @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @orm:Column(type="string", length="255")
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

I have this yaml

```
Blog\WebBundle\Entity\Posts:
  type: entity
  table: posts
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    title:
      type: string
      length: 255
      fixed: false
      nullable: false
    content:
      type: text
      nullable: false
    uid:
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And the Entity is generated:

```
<?php

namespace Blog\WebBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Blog\WebBundle\Entity\Posts
 */
class Posts
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var text $content
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var integer $uid
     */
    private $uid;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string $title
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param text $content
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return text $content
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set uid
     *
     * @param integer $uid
     */
    public function setUid($uid)
    {
        $this->uid = $uid;
    }

    /**
     * Get uid
     *
     * @return integer $uid
     */
    public function getUid()
    {
        return $this->uid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit `vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Command/DoctrineCommand.php`

Change `$entityGenerator->setGenerateAnnotations(false);` to `true`

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want your entity to have annotations when you already have your mapping in a YAML document. I think maybe this is why it doesn't add annotations into your generated entities?

(I don't know for sure, I don't generate my entities)

Comment: For not see DB structure or YML files.. But I'v already fix it, by adding some think like this `$this->setAnnotations(true)` in generator